# Word 2013 activate "New" screen from VSTO

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-2013, word-addins

I'm developing a Word AddIn, and I've run into a bit of a problem.

I need to modify the BuiltIn BuildingBlocks, and to do that, I need an active document.

Since Word 2013 no longer starts with an open document, but instead shows the "New (Latest)" screen, my AddIn creates a new temporary document, modifies the BuildingBlocks as it should, and then discards the temporary document.

The problem is that the act of opening a new document and closing it again, leaves the Word UI at the Home-tab with no active document open, instead of on the "New" screen as it normally would.

So my question is: How do I make Word switch back to the "New" screen?

Here is the before screen, showing normal Word 2013 behaviour on startup:
[image: Normal Word 2013 (Danish)]

Here is the after screen, showing how it ends up now, because I open/close the document at startup:
[image: Gery Word 2013 (Danish)]

Sorry about the danish screenshots, but the principle should still be clear.

I'm using VB.Net, but C# code can be used too, since it is easily translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to show the Startup screen again. Instead, you may consider running a new Word instance.

Be aware, the Word object model provides the [ScreenUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197438(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Application class which you may find helpful. Here is what MSDN states:

*The ScreenUpdating property controls most display changes on the monitor while a procedure is running. When screen updating is turned off, toolbars remain visible and Word still allows the procedure to display or retrieve information using status bar prompts, input boxes, dialog boxes, and message boxes. You can increase the speed of some procedures by keeping screen updating turned off. You must set the ScreenUpdating property to True when the procedure finishes or when it stops after an error.*

Comment: I half suspected there would be no way :-(

The ScreenUpdating property doesn't seem to prevent the Start Screen from vanishing when creating a new document, even if the document is set to hidden,

Answer (score 1):

You may also create a template file with building blocks, then attach the template on top of the new document

It will solve you problem

Comment: If I needed to add Building Blocks, you are absolutely correct.

But I needed to remove some of the default Building Blocks, and an extra template cannot do that :-(